# Altering column with index on it in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

#### Version

SQL enginie: MS SQL.

EF Core packages versions:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

---

#### Problem

I've changed the existing column, which had index on it created few migrations earlier:

```
// ... other changes
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Interactions_OrganisationToId",
    table: "Interactions",
    column: "OrganisationToId");
```

I've changed it from optional to required (not-nullable).
Entity Framework Core generated such a migration:

```
// ... other changes
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(
    name: "OrganisationToId",
    table: "Interactions",
    nullable: false);
```

But you cannot alter the column which has index on it. Unfortunately EF Core is not supporting this in case of changing field to non-nullable.

When renaming field - works like a charm and before rename simply drops index and restores it after alter.

---

#### Question

Is there any way to configure EF Core that he'll cover this case and generate correct migration?

Comment: This is fixed in EFCore 1.1.0. See issue [#6102](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6102)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment I've modified the migration and dropped down the index before altering the column, and manually restore it after the operation.

It did the job.

```
// drop index before altering column
migrationBuilder.DropIndex(name: "IX_Interactions_OrganisationToId", table: "Interactions");

// actually altering column
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(
   name: "OrganisationToId",
   table: "Interactions",
   nullable: false);

// restore index
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
   name: "IX_Interactions_OrganisationToId",
   table: "Interactions",
   column: "OrganisationToId");
```